# Twitter Bootstrap does not add padding to the body when displaying the modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When Bootrap's modal is shown, Bootstrap adds a `15px` padding to the `body` to prevent the page from moving to the right as the scrollbar disappears. You can check it out here at their [website](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals). Bootstrap always calculates the width of the scrollbar before showing the modal so the padding is applied only if there is scrollbar. However every time I use the modal in my projects, Bootstrap always calculates the scrollbar width as 0(zero) even when the scrollbar is present and no padding is ever applied. I always use their latest script and css. This happens to me no matter what browser I use. Can't figure out why the width always seem to be calculated as 0.

Comment: Does your body have an overflow-x:hidden style on it?

Comment: It would help if you link a sample of your page that has a problem with the bootstrap modal. Or at least a fiddle of your code.